# PHP fetch_assoc loop

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

My query selects all rows that match a certain criteria, but I encountered a problem when using fetch_assoc for this, i only get one row.

This is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT filename, comment, action FROM files WHERE belongsto = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['case_identifer']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
echo json_encode(array(($result->fetch_assoc())));
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

I need to turn the fetch_assoc function into a loop so that I get ALL results in the JSON, but I'm very unsure on how to perform this, would appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: The [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for the function you're talking about already has an example of doing exactly this! It doesn't encode it to JSON (but that's a separate step you do once you're ready to output the data) but it shows the looping you're talking about. 1000 other mysqli examples online would show the same, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a while loop to write the rows to an array and then json_encode that. So replace this line:

```
echo json_encode(array(($result->fetch_assoc())));
```

with this loop:

```
$output = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Thanks, im just confused in regard to what's what here. What do I replace for this in my code?

Comment: @zugo123456789 I've updated my answer to make it more clear as to what to do.